# python re.compile match dosn't match backward slash in full path in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a windows full path which I try to validate using regex. According to [this](https://sceweb.sce.uhcl.edu/helm/WEBPAGE-Python/documentation/howto/regex/node8.html)
I have to add `"\\\\\\\\"` but this is not working.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import re

regex1 = re.compile('downloads\\\\test_dir\\\\sql\\\\my-ee.sql')  
s = "C:\x\xxx\temp\downloads\test_dir\sql\my-ee.sql"  
gg = regex1.match(s)
```

`gg` is `None`.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error

Comment: [`match()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) will return smth only if whole string matches pattern, you probably want to use [`search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). `re.search(re.escape(r"downloads\test_dir\sql\my-ee.sql"), s)`

Comment: In this form, `s` should contain ```\\```-s.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Small correction: not whole string. Only from the beginning. To match the whole string there is [`fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yes, missed that and it was too late to edit, thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two things:

1. The assignment of `s` should be either with escaped back-slashes or as a raw string. I prefer the latter:

```
s = r"C:\x\xxx\temp\downloads\test_dir\sql\my-ee.sql"
```

2. you should use the `search` method instead of `match` to be content with a partial match.

Then, you can use `\\\\` in the regular expression, or  - as I prefer - a raw string again:

```
import re

regex1 = re.compile(r'downloads\\test_dir\\sql\\my-ee.sql')  
s = r"C:\x\xxx\temp\downloads\test_dir\sql\my-ee.sql"  
gg = regex1.search(s)
print(gg)
```